# Symfony generate unique random int value

Tags: php, database, symfony

Hey is there any component in symfony to generate random unique a string of numbers?

I need generate 10 unique random numbers i saw uuid,ulid components, but there generate string numbers and letters.

Answer (score 0):

Why using symfony to generate random numbers ?

You can use PHP => [random_int()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)

```
random_int(min, max)
```

Edit :

If you want unique string of number :

You can use `microtime(true)` to get current timestamp with microseconds, and then multiply with `random_int()`, even if only microtime(true) should be enough.

Note : you have to remove `.` from `microtime(true)`

```
echo str_replace(".", "", microtime(true)) * random_int(1000, 100000);
```

Comment: Because i need that value unique in my database i thought is any symfon component to generate it quickly without create custom function

Comment: Maybe you can add microtime(), to get current timestamp with microseconds, it should be unique, and after multiply with random int  :  `str_replace(".", "", microtime(true)) * random_int(1000, 100000)`

Comment: hmm i think better option will be generate rand(10000, 99999) and check if exist in database, but i thought it can be do using framework components

Comment: finally i do recursive function 
    public function generate()
    {
        $rand = rand(100000000000, 999999999999); 

        if(!empty($this->em->getRepository(Giftcard::class)->findGiftcard($rand))){
            return $this->generate();
        }

        return $rand;
    }